# Trembling Sprites cocos2dx 3.0

Tags: c++, opengl-es, cocos2d-x

I notice Sprite trembling while moving down with acceleration.. here is the whole code:
I am testing this code with iPhone 3gs, any guesses why?

TestScene.h       :

```
class TestScene : public Layer {
public:
    ....
    virtual void update(float delta);

    float spawnTime = 0.9;
    float untilNextSpawn = 0;

    virtual void spawn();
    float gameSpeed = 200;
    float gameAcceleration = 10;
    Vector<Sprite*> objects;
};
```

TestScene.cpp     :

```
 void TestScene::update(float delta) {
     untilNextSpawn -= delta;
     if (untilNextSpawn <= 0) {
         spawn();
         untilNextSpawn = spawnTime;
     }

     gameSpeed += gameAcceleration * delta;

     for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
         Sprite* t = objects.at(i);
         if (t->getPosition().y <= 0)
             t->setVisible(false);
         else 
             t->setPositionY(t->getPositionY() - gameSpeed * delta);
    }
}

void TestScene::spawn() {
    Sprite* sprite = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
        Sprite* t = objects.at(i);
        if (!t->isVisible()) {
            sprite = t; break;  
        }
    }
    if (!sprite) {
        sprite = Sprite::create("prefab_button.png");
        this->addChild(sprite);
        objects.pushBack(sprite);
    }
    sprite->setVisible(true);
    sprite->setPosition(Point(getContentSize().width / 2, getContentSize().height + 100));
}
```

prefab_button.png : https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vHCP.png

TestScene.h : http://pastebin.com/f9sSTLgp

TestScene.cpp : http://pastebin.com/siipLzx6

And here's video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PYfzUnSBQ7M

Comment: Don't post links. If the code is too long, cut it down to a minimal testcase.

Comment: try to check x and y position that always same or not....

Comment: why? it can't be same

Comment: can you explain in `spawn()` why you are setting `sprite = t` in a loop, then once the loop is done checking `(!sprite)` which is really just the same as the last time through the loop, then re-setting sprite in the `(!sprite) and re-adding back to the same vector you read them out of in the loop. There is no need for the use of `Sprite* t` either....

Comment: When sprite is off the screen I am hiding it, and then when I have to spawn some sprite, at first I check if I have some object off the screen and then use it, otherwise I have to create new one and then add it to screen and array.

Comment: Here is the video if someone needed it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PYfzUnSBQ7M